# Laravel package database

Tags: laravel-4

Is it possible to specify another database connection in a new Laravel workbench package in the config/database.php file? I am printing out the connections, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make Laravel's ConnectionResolver aware of the package's connection settings.

In your Laravel package's ServiceProvider's boot() method, you can set this using the following:

```
\Config::set('database.connections.yourdb',
    \Config::get('package::database.connections.yourdb'));
```

where `yourdb` is the name of your package's connection in your `src/config/database.php` file, and `package` is the **lowercase name** of your package (example: in a workbench package named Somevendor\Somepackage, the package would be "somepackage").

Now in your package's model, simply use:

```
protected $connection = 'yourdb';
```

Source: excellent blog post by Ryan Tablada here: http://ryantablada.com/post/laravel-package-database-flexibility-eloquent-models

Comment: Instead of setting the connection on the Model. I put `Config::set('database.default', 'yourdb');` underneath the line you put in the boot() method

Comment: but would doing that change it for just the scope of the package or for all of laravel?